# singleton class in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I know singleton class is not supporting in Flex.Because it does not access private constructor.

But i want to make a class is singleton class. Please anyone can explain with example.

Thanks,
Ravi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A singleton is a class of which only one instance will be created. This instance will be shared by all other code in the program.

A singleton in the strictest sense is not supported in ActionScript because a constructor cannot be marked *private*. Consequently, additional instances of the class could be created elsewhere in the program. With the following trick, you can ensure that the constructor is only called by the singleton class itself:

```
package {

public final class Singleton {

    private static var instance:Singleton = new Singleton();

    public function Singleton() {
        if( Singleton.instance ) {
            throw new Error( 
                "Singleton and can only be accessed through Singleton.getInstance()" ); 
        }
    }

    public static function getInstance():Singleton {                        
        return Singleton.instance;
    }
}
}
```