# How to perform repetitive actions in PureMVC flex application?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, puremvc

Currently working on a flex AIR project based on PureMVC framework. There was a new requirement to the project, an operation is to be performed repetitively at regular interval which has some business logic. As per PureMVC this should be placed in the command, but then command would get garbage collected the moment its executed.

Given the scenario there are few doubts/confusions/clarifications...

1. Creating a command with business logic would be one solution ... but then who would trigger it at specific interval? (shouldn't this be done by a command as per PureMVC)
2. Placing the command trigger in a mediator or placing the logic in a mediator (this would make pureMVC a bit impure :) )

How do I find a solution for this kind of scenario?

Comment: AFAIK commands _are_ for business logic. So I suppose you mean something else? Why would it matter that the command geta garbage collected? Does it need to store state? That's what models are for. Or does it need to control a sequential async process? Or probably we're using different definitions of business logic. Since this is about PureMVC I'm using the definition from the PureMVC best practices: http://puremvc.org/component/option,com_wrapper/Itemid,174/

Comment: You are correct commands are for business logic. I have a sequential async process to be run in the background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pull apart the async process you want to run and the repetitive triggering of said process. My advice is to create a Proxy for the async process and a separate Proxy that's a wrapper for a Timer which simply sends a notification upon timeout. The notification is coupled to a command, which in turn calls the async proxy's methods. That way you can add logic to the command for instance what to do if the process is still busy.

The benefits of creating two proxies: you adhere to SRP. You can easily swap/modify/remove the timing proxy w/o touching the async proxy. Everything is nicely separated.

Answer (score 1):

depends on what the `Command` should do - if it updates the `Model` put a `Timer` in one of your `Proxy` class and send a `Notification` every xx seconds which is mapped to a `Command` that does whatever it is you want it to do.

If it should just update the `View` you could add the `Timer` to the corresponding `Mediator` but then you wouldn't need a `Command` at all.

**

Don't create more Singletons than you need. `ApplicationFacade` is already one - try and keep it that way.

**

If you have to do any async calls to the backend, just make sure to add the `EventListener` without `weakReference` set to true - then everything should be ok...

Comment: I don't think adding another singleton would be an appropriate solution in my case. As of now I have added the timer to a mediator and sending notification to call the command. I don't think which is right solution anyways, but then I have to manage with this. Adding timer to proxy is a good workaround. Thanks!!!

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

- Create a Singleton class - [singleton class in Flex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217152/singleton-class-in-flex)
- Have a function in this class (eg. called start) that when called starts a timer, the callback function of which sends a notification, that triggers a command that does your business logic.
- When you are ready to start your regular actions simply call the get instance method on your singleton, to create the singleton and then call it's start() function.
  *Optionally have a stop function that cancels the timer and stops the regular notifications being sent.

  ```
  package
  {
   import flash.events.TimerEvent;
   import flash.utils.Timer;


   public final class RepititiveSingleton
   {
      private var timer:Timer;

      private static var instance:RepititiveSingleton= new RepititiveSingleton();

      public function RepititiveSingleton() {
          if( RepititiveSingleton.instance ) {
              throw new Error( 
                  "ReptitiveSingleton can only be accessed through Singleton.getInstance()" ); 
          }
      }

      public static function getInstance():RepititiveSingleton{                        
          return RepititiveSingleton.instance;
      }

      public function start(interval:Number = 1000):void {
          timer = new Timer(interval);
          timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, onTimer);
      }

      private function onTimer(e:TimerEvent):void {
                   ApplicationFacade.getInstance().sendNotification(Constants.REPTITIVE_ACTION_NOTIFICATION));
      }

   }
  }
  ```

This code assumes that you have your Concrete facade named ApplicationFacade, and have registered a notification using a String constant that is referenced from a class called constants.

Then in an appropriate place (maybe in your startup command) you can add:

```
RepetitiveSingleton.getInstance().start();
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score -1):

IMO, the timer belongs in a mediator. Let it- well, *mediate* the asynch process messaging. It will be a little state machine to make sure everything is running smoothly. Commands still do the heavy lifting, it just sits around like a 911 operator.